# Team Build - Get Workspace - get latest from specific paths, NOT everything

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a simple build definition which I want to use to build just one project, and every time I choose to run this build, I want to get latest from the branch/directories that pertain only to the project in question. How do I do that? The call to "Get Workspace" gets **everything** from source control, and I do not want to (or need to, for that matter) get latest from everything for various reasons.

I hope I am not asking for much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so I got around doing what I wanted to do using the DownloadFiles activity (using TFS 2010). In the workflow, I simply removed the GetWorkspace activity. So far I am content.

Comment: What are your `Workspace` settings in your build definition? You should have only those parts needed for this build.

Answer (score 4):

Check the workspace mapping in the build definition. The build only gets the items that you have specified over there. If you want to exclude some folders within the path that you are mapping, you can choose to cloak some folders.

Comment: Correct -- set this in your build definition and not in your build process template.

Comment: this can be a tedious job when you have tons of folders with big data. How can you configure TFS to just get the items that are mentioned in the solution file?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your `ItemsToBuild` in `Process Tab` in `Required section`

[image]

Comment: This is the way I have had it set up but it was still getting latest from all.

Comment: yes, this will not change what is downloaded by TFS Build. It just specifies what needs to be compiled. It seems that the GetWorkspaces in the Build process template should be updated, but not sure on how to do this.