# TFS Build copies complete Repository for build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

we have setup TFS Build for our project, but on every build the system copies the whole repository and then compiles our solution. How can we make sure TFS Build only downloads the files needed for the solution without having to cloak each un-needed directory manually ? Now it downloads over 2GIGs of data just to compile a project that is less then 100mb in size (source files). The other data are test databases and files that are not needed for the automatic build.

**EDIT**:
some further investigation let me to some keywords for searching. These posts are helping out:
[Team Build - Get Workspace - get latest from specific paths, NOT everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732642/team-build-get-workspace-get-latest-from-specific-paths-not-everything)

[TFS Build and workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949770/tfs-build-and-workspace)

still investigating though. Any comments are welcome.

**EDIT**:
An option is to replace CreateWorkspace in the Build process definition with my own extended activity. I'm hoping to find out that somebody already did.. basically you would use the VersionControlServer object to download the necessary files instead of the whole workspace.

**EDIT**
There is currently no real good answer / solution to this. I gave some options and the people that responded gave some alternatives, but you can't easily change the TFS Build process to just download the data that is part of the solution instead of the whole repository. So be aware when you are building your repository.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the `Build Definition` mapping to only include the source you wish to compile.  This means that you don't have to `cloak` any thing.

- Edit Build Configuration
- Click on Source Settings (VS 2012), Workspace (VS 2010)
- An example specific mapping would look like this:

<kbd>Status</kbd><kbd>Source Control Folder</kbd>                           <kbd>Build Agent Folder</kbd>                
<kbd>Active</kbd><kbd>$/Path/To/The/SolutionOrProjectFolder</kbd>  <kbd>$(SourceDir)\</kbd>

This will make the `workspace` for this build be limited to the solution that you wish to build.  Therefore only AssemblyInfo files under that will be visible to your build activity.

**If you cannot do this due to how your source control is setup, then I would suggest restructuring your folders within your `Source Control`.**

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one Build Agent, you should limit the number of agents that the build definition can run against. That will stop multiple copies of the same source been downloaded on to the build machine(s).

The next part you have already answered in you question, by changing the "Clean Workspace" option in your Build Definition to **None** the build agent will only download the changesets between the current and last build.

Comment: this is helpful, we do have multiple build agents, but i would rather find a way to limit the download of files to the files that are only in the solution. I'm surprised to see that this doesn't seem to be available by default.

Comment: You could look into tfs cloak option, if the amount of stuff outside solution is so large to be a concern than perhaps you should reorganize your content. For general Daves answear is correct - Clean Workspace settings Output or None will limit amount of source downloaded. Going further you can implement central workspace for all agents and/or have custom source get.

Comment: @invalidusername If it's disk space you're concerned about, then go with what I said, if the problem is NW bandwidth, look into a TFS proxy.

Comment: @invalidusername I think Dave makes a good point about the build agents, but setting the **Clean Workspace** value to **none** can cause problems if you're not aware of how it works. When this setting is set to **none** then automated builds can get stuck if the previous build failed. If your build automation process can be allowed to get "stuck" once in a while, then setting **Clean Workspace** to **none** should be okay; otherwise, I would recommend setting it to **outputs**.